# remover um commit indevido da história mas manter as mudanças atuais nos arquivos

Tags: git, github

Eu clonei um repositório remoto e logo após isso precisei puxar alguns arquivos de uma branch especifica e parece que disso foi feito um merge (sem querer) na própria master, depois criei uma nova branch (apartir da master) com o comando `git checkout -b nova_branch`, fiz algumas modificações e depois dei um `push` dessa nova branch para o repositório remoto (ela não existia remotamente), e aconteceu que além do meu trabalho também foi 
 enviado o histórico da branch que eu havia feito dado um `pull` (o qual ocorreu o merge indevido), só que não queria que isso tivesse acontecido, como posso remover essa branch que não deveria ter sido "merjada" e remover ele da história/log, tanto local como remota, mas manter as modificações dos últimos commits?

o log está assim:

```
69ddf1d09a108a5989a67e955273853c (HEAD) -> mais recente (commit com as modificações corretas)
3a39b68b00aaf809165adae9a5897f86 -> correções corrretas
c6d496b50e63c91cb40b970b568803a9 -> correções corretas
1da606decbfc2832a91af185dc0013c9 (master) -> commit "errado", o qual foi puxado de uma branch remota e que quero excluir da história/log.
```

pensei em usar o `reset --soft 1da606decbfc2832a91af185dc0013c9`, isso seria uma boa solução?

**EDIT:**

Para melhor exemplificar, segue imagem do github:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**circulado em vermelho estão os históricos que vieram do branch que eu dei merge sem querer e quero remover.**

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, para sumir com o commit indesejado do histórico e remover as alterações feitas por ele, faça um rebase da sua nova branch:

```bsh
git rebase -i 1da606^
```

Então quando o editor de texto abrir, remova a primeira linha do arquivo, a qual será o commit indesejado, e salve.

Se der conflito, resolva o conflito e continue `git rebase --continue`.

Com isso preservará as alterações da sua branch atual, removerá as alterações do commit 1da606 e apagará o histórico do merge indesejado.

Comment: O que significa esse ^ no final do hash?

Comment: exibiu a lista de commit com "pick", mas não mostrou o commit do "merge", é assim mesmo?

no caso, só exibiu os 3 commits corretos como falei lá em cima

Comment: O ^ é para se referir ao primeiro pai do commit 1da606. Em termos gerais, a ideia é conectar seu branch direto no commit pai principal do commit do merge.

Comment: Deveria exibir o commit do merge e você apagar a linha. Você usou o ^?

Comment: Não sabia, pensei que era uma abreviação para não escrever o hash inteiro, deu um conflito, tive que resolver com reset, mas obrigado